# ionic 2 - detect shake device when app in background mode

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want create application with ionic 2 that it send sms when user shaked mobile and so my app must be in background mode

I search and find this plugin for set app to background

```
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode
```

but how detect shake device when use this plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the `background-plugin`, but if it lets you run the app indefinitely in the background, you should be able to use the shake plugin to detect shakes: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/shake/

Try to add

```
const watch = this.shake.startWatch(60).subscribe(() => {
  // do something
});
```

to your `app.component.ts` and see if it works.